# Mysql trigger after update New is wrong

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created a trigger that on a table update inserts row into another table, but one of the values that I pass is getting the old value of the table I am updating.

This is the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ordersHistory
AFTER UPDATE
   ON orders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
        INSERT INTO test (`test`) VALUES (NEW.ourNotes);
        INSERT INTO test (`test`) VALUES (OLD.ourNotes);
    END IF;
END $$
```

This insert at the table exactly the same thing.(the old value of ourNotes)

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dfb5bea2335bd5834f9a78d7fa09ff0

Comment: Your inserts happen after every update that changes `status`, so if only `status` changes and `ourNotes` remains the same, both `NEW.ourNotes` and `OLD.OurNotes` will have the same value.

Comment: The problem was that there were multiple updates happening (around 3 ) trigger wasnt insert any except the last. I couldnt figure out a solution to this so I change the way I am changing the value of ourNotes. Thank you for your time.